# SQL IF statement with 3 alternatives

Tags: sql, if-statement, ms-access-2010, calculated-columns

Hey guys i could really use some help coding this IF statement! I managed to fit in 2 of the conditions, not sure how the 3rd (calculation) would fit in. This is the calc in pseudocode;

```
IF Producer_Type = 'Oil', Unallocated OIL&GAS = UnallocatedLossesOIL
IF Producer_Type = 'Gas', Unallocated OIL&GAS = UnallocatedLossesGAS
ELSE Unallocated OIL GAS = UnallocatedLossesOIL(MPPOil ÷ (MPPOil + MPPGas)) + 
UnallocatedLossesGAS(MPPGas ÷ (MPPOil + MPPGas))
```

This is my code:

```
SELECT qb1.CompanyName, qb1.AssetName, qb1.Year, 
IIf(qb1.Producer_Type='Oil',qb1.DatapointValue, qb2.DatapointValue) AS UnallocatedOilGas
FROM PEBaseQuery AS qb1 INNER JOIN PEBaseQuery AS qb2 ON qb1.Assetname=qb2.AssetName
WHERE qb1.DatapointID=2026 And qb2.DatapointID=2027;
```

Where DatapointID of 2026 is UnallocatedLossesOIL and 2027 is UnallocatedLossesGAS. The calculation needs to reference MPPOil and MPPGas values (relating to particular companies/assets/yearswhich are results from two separate queries... Any help would be much appreciated! Sorry if some of this doesnt make sense..

Comment: Is `UnallocatedLossesOIL` a function, or are you intending its adjacency to the parentheses to imply multiplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about nesting the if condition? I mean, if thats possible, this should work:

```
SELECT qb1.CompanyName, qb1.AssetName, qb1.Year, 
IIf(qb1.Producer_Type='Oil', qb1.DatapointValue, 
  IIF(qb1.Producer_Type='Gas', qb2.DatapointValue,
   qb1.DatapointValue * (MPPOil / (MPPOil + MPPGas)) + 
   qb2.DatapointValue * (MPPGas / (MPPOil + MPPGas)) )) AS UnallocatedOilGas
FROM PEBaseQuery AS qb1 INNER JOIN PEBaseQuery AS qb2 ON qb1.Assetname=qb2.AssetName
WHERE qb1.DatapointID=2026 And qb2.DatapointID=2027;
```

Regarding the values of `MPPGas` and `MPPOil`, I'm not sure where to find them, so left them as they are.
I hope this works.

Comment: +1 I think a `case` might be clearer, not sure if Access supports that